# Dynamic update of model constrains and objective function parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7, gurobi

I'm looking for some help to optimize my code execution.

I build up a Model Predictive Control and I use Gurobi QP solver to solve the QP problem on-line.

For each sample time the code create a new model, variables and constrains. The structure of the problem doesn't change during a single simulation, but change the value of coefficients of constraints and objective function.

I want to find a way to update this coefficients due to reduce the time execution of the solver.

Now more than 60% of time execution was passed in build new constrain each time.

In the code example, the QP problem is:

Objective function: x^t H x + F^t x |||  Constrains: A x <= b

F,A and b are matrix that change each time step.

```
%Code Example

import numpy as N
import gurobipy as gpy
m=gpy.Model()
H=mpcSim.H
A_cons=N.asarray(mpcSim.A_cons)
b=N.asarray(mpcSim.b)
F=mpcSim.F

n_cons,n_stato=A_cons.shape

x={}
for ii in range(n_stato):
    x[ii]=m.addVar(lb=-1e20,ub=1e20,name='x{}'.format(ii))

m.update()    

for ii in range(n_cons):
    m.addConstr(gpy.quicksum(A_cons[ii,jj]*x[jj] for jj in range(n_stato)), gpy.GRB.LESS_EQUAL, b[ii,0],name='Const{}'.format(ii))
m.update()

obj1=gpy.quicksum(gpy.quicksum(H[ii,jj]*x[ii] for ii in range(n_stato))*x[jj] for jj in range(n_stato))
obj2=gpy.quicksum(F[ii,0]*x[ii] for ii in range(n_stato))


m.setObjective(obj1+obj2)

m.optimize()
```

Thanks in advance,

Jack

Comment: I wonder if it will be easier to help if you post some code

Comment: Are the matrices A_cons and H sparse?

Comment: The matrix A_cons is sparse, but the matrix H is full.